# is any alternative methods are available in AWS Autoscaling with CodeDeploy..?

Tags: autoscaling, cicd, aws-code-deploy

I need to deploy my application with autoscalling group, but the scenaer is need CI/CD i have enabled codedeploy but my image have 3 different applications. so everytime my code updated through AWS-CodeDeploy my other updated versions code alsio destroied. so i need an alternative solution for CodeDeploy.